# Show that $n^2+n$ is even for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by contradiction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, natural-numbers

> Show that $n^2+n$ is even for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by contradiction.

My attempt: assume that $n^2+n$ is odd, then $n^2+n=2k+1$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

We have that 
$$n^2+n=2k+1 \Leftrightarrow \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}=2k+1\Leftrightarrow n=\sqrt{2k+\frac{5}{4}}-\frac{1}{2}.$$

Choosing $k=1$, we have that $n=\sqrt{2+\frac{5}{4}}-\frac{1}{2}\notin\mathbb{N}$, so we have a contradiction because $n^2+n=2k+1$ should be verified for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Is this correct or wrong? If wrong, can you tell me where and why? Thanks.

Comment: You've shown that $n=2\times 1 +1=3$ is not a counterexample, but you need to show that there are no counterexamples at all.

Comment: You can't choose $k$ it's a function of $n$.

Comment: It's wrong on many levels, but the first thing is: You can't say "for all $k$". It is for each $n$, there is some $k$ such that ..

Comment: I'd start from the fact that $n^2+n=n\times (n+1)$.  If that's odd we see that $n,n+1$ must both be odd.  Can you have two consecutive odd integers?

Comment: If $n$ is odd say $n=2k+1$ then 
$$n^2=(2k+1)^2=(2k+1)\times (2k+1)=2\times(k(2k+2))+1\quad\text{is odd}$$
hence necessary $n$ is even

Comment: "assume that n2+n is odd, then n2+n=2k+1 for all k∈N."  I need to nitpick and point out this doesn't mean what you think it does.  This means that $n^2 +n$ equals every odd number at all times.  That is $n^2 + n = 7$ and $n^2 + n = 15$ and $n^2 + n = 1$ and therefore all odd numbers are equal so $7 = 15$ because $n^2+n = 7$ *and* $n^2 + 2 = 15$ (at the same time!)  This is not what you mean.  You mean that $n^2 + n = 2k+1$ for *SOME* integer $k$.  .... And your proof doesn't work because $k$ doesn't have to be equal to $1$.

Comment: Thanks to all for you useful comments, especially timur and fleablood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other users have already pointed out your big mistake: you can’t say that $n^2+n=2k+1$ **for all $\mathbf k$**, since being odd only means that this is true for a **specific $\mathbf k$**. We can complete your proof as follows. If $n^2+n=2k+1$, by your same calculation, $$n=\sqrt{2k+\frac54}-\frac12=\frac12\left(\sqrt{8k+5}-1\right).$$ However, $8k+5$ isn’t a square **for any $\mathbf k$** (as a square must give a remainder of $0$, $1$ or $4$ when divided by $8$), so that, even when assuming the original statement for a single $k$, we arrive at the contradiction that $n$ is irrational. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's exactly what I was searching for. To be sure: when you say "for a specific $k$" you mean something logically equivalent to $\forall n\in\mathbb{N} \exists k_n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n^2+n=2k+1$ or something else?

Comment: @Dunkelheit Almost. Since this is a proof by contradiction, we’d be assuming $\exists n\exists k\left(n^2+n=2k+1\right)$. After getting to a contradiction, we’d arrive at the negation of this statement, $\forall n\not\exists k\left(n^2+n=2k+1\right)$, which could be then translated into English as “for all $n$, $n^2+n$ is not odd, i.e. even.”

Answer (score 4):

You can't choose $k$ here; you have to show it's true for all of them. I would prove it this way. Assume $n^2+n$ is odd. This means $n(n+1)$ is odd, but that's impossible, because a number and its successor can't both be odd.

Comment: We might note that contradiction is redundant in this proof, as you proved that $n^2+n$ was even directly.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a true proof by contradiction to me, either

Comment: But the fact the original question asks for a proof by contradiction is a bit weird

Comment: @URL Yes, absolutely, I intentionally chose to restate a direct proof in a logically equivalent form to meet the requirements. Trivial problems demand trivial solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to be the bearer of bad tidings, but the presented proof attempt is flawed.  There is no guarantee that *any* $k$ corresponds to a given $n^2 + n$, so the assumption that

$\forall n \in \Bbb N, \exists k \in \Bbb Z, \; n^2 + n = 2k + 1 \tag 1$

is erroneous.

I prove it like this:  if $n$ is odd, then $n + 1$ is even; so whether $n$ is odd or even, we have $2 \mid n(n + 1)$, i.e., $n(n + 1)$ is even.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure if I've understood a thing: you say that the assumption (1) is erroneous and I agree with you if you mean that is erroneous in general, so without assuming by contradiction that $n^2+n$ is odd. However I have a question: in this case, by contradiction, I can assume $n^2+n$ odd and so I can use (1) to obtain a contradiction or you say that not even in this case (1) mean something?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $n^2 + n$ is odd for all natural numbers $n$. Then $n(n+1)$, the product of two consecutive integers, is also odd. However, an odd number can not have any even factors. Either $n$ is odd, and $n+1$ is even, or $n$ is even and $n+1$ is odd, as they are consecutive integers. The product $n(n+1)$ has one even and one odd factor, which contradicts our previous statement that $n(n+1)$ is odd, as an odd number times an even number is an even number.

Answer (score 2):

To be different.  Suppose there some natural number where this is true.  But it isn't true for $1$ or $2$.  But if there is some value where it *is* true there must be some *first* value, $n$ where it is true.

So suppose that $n^2 + n$ is odd but $(n-1)^2 + (n-1)$ is not odd.  Then $n^2 - 2n + 1+ n-1 = n^2-n + 2$ is even. So $n^2 - n + 2 = 2k$ for some $k$.

So $n^2 - n + 2 + (2n-2) = 2k + (2n-2) = 2(k+n -1)$ is even.  But $n^2 - n + 2 + (2n-2)=n^2 + n$ which we assumed was odd.

The advantage of this proof is that we don't have to assume that if $n^2 + n = n(n+1)$ is odd that means $n$ and $n+1$ are both odd (why is that so?) and that it is impossible for $n$ and $n+1$ to both be odd (why is that so?).

The disadvantage of this proof is it's abstract and not straightforward.